# Proper escape LIKE conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, sql-like

I want to use `LIKE` in my SQL request. I constructed something like this:

```
streets = Street.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

as [mentioned](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) in Rails Guides. And I thought that it is totally OK. But I faced with following troubles:

If I user put with parentheses in `params[:name]` I catch an error. Example with `params[:name] = '('`:

```
Street Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `streets`.* FROM `streets` WHERE (name LIKE '%(%')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

RegexpError (end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /(/):
```

If I user put with slash in `params[:name]` I catch an error. Example with `params[:name] = "a\\p"`:

```
invalid multibyte character
```

I expected array style of request to escape all the special character, but it doesn't!

What should I do to escape `LIKE` request properly?

I'm using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

P.S. I found [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fe4b0eee05f59831e1468ed50f55fbad0ce11e1d) authored 2 month ago. So Rails developers just started to fix this problem... So It seems to be only external solution (like some gem or some hacking)

Comment: @Pavan, It will be just string `name = ?, '%(%'` that will not be recognized by SQL server.

Comment: And also as it said, it is not safe as it can leave you vulnerable to SQL injection exploits